# Lazy loading specific entities in Doctrine 2

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I have quite a trivial question/problem, but I haven't found any satisfiable answer.

I have a simple entity in Doctrine 2 specifying configuration options (just ID, name and value). During rendering different pages throughout my code, I'm requesting different configuration options by name, which results in a query for each one of those requests.

But I actually need the values only in the template. So I want to somehow squeeze all the different calls into one query, that will execute and fetch all the options I've requested. I cannot build a custom DQL because I don't know which options will each page want (and building every combination seems stupid as hell to me).

I thought about a very naive implementation of some weird lazy loading, but it turns out I don't have much knowledge in this field. Is there any possibility for Doctrine to do this automatically?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

What is the problem? If you don't want to call database query in every request, cache those queries in Redis, Memcached, APC etc...
Doctrine out of the box support eager, lazy and extra lazy loading for related entities to another.